# Better solution than lex/yacc for parsing a DSL in C?

Tags: c, parsing, dsl

One of my programs accepts a commands (like `kill foo`) at runtime. Think of it as a little domain-specific language. Here are a few examples:

```
kill
kill client
exit
```

But also, chained commands are allowed and whitespace is not significant before and after commands, so the following examples are also valid:

```
kill ; say "that was fun"
  kill  ;  kill      ; kill;
```

I have currently implemented this with lex/yacc (flex/bison to be specific) and that caused a lot of headache. The lexer very much depends on the context (for example whitespace tokens are generally not returned, unless after a `kill` keyword for example) and has many different states. The grammar used to have conflicts and I don’t really like the format in which it has to be specified (especially the $1, $2, $3, … to use arguments for non-terminals). Also, the error messages which bison provides (at parse-time) are sometimes accurate, but often not (the `kill` command with optional arguments leads to error messages like `Unexpected $undefined, expected $end or ;` for `kill clont` instead of `kill client`). Lastly, the C API for yacc is cruel (external defines all over the place).

I am not asking you to solve all the aforementioned questions (I will open separate threads with more specific descriptions and code if there is no way around lex/yacc). Instead, I am interested in alternatives to lex/yacc.

My criteria are the following:

- Input is a string (const char *), there is no output but instead some code should be called for each different keyword.
- I want to use this with C (C99).
- The software should be already included in the major linux distros or at least easy to bundle / package.
- It should be well-documented.
- The syntax for describing my language should be easy.
- It should output meaningful error messages upon parsing errors.
- Performance is not that important (of course it should be fast, but the typical use case is interactive usage, not processing tons of MB of commands).

Comment: @Philip: Yeah, you kind of get the feeling I had after messing with all the lexer/parser stuff… :)

Answer (score 3):

As for a very simple and small grammar, I'd consider writing the lexer/parser by hand - it's often not that much work.

Virtually all linux distros ship a variant of lex/yacc. Other than that, two other widely used parser generators are [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) and [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Since your language looks pretty simple, I suggest implementing a finite state machine that tokenizes and parses the input.

Simply read the input one character at a time, tokenizing at whitespace (while not in a quoted string). Each "command" takes the machine in a different state where it parses the command arguments. ";" or "\n" reset the machine to its start state.

Comment: Thanks for the short explanation on how this might look like. Actually, my language is a little bit more complex (I only revealed the easy parts of it in the question), but nevertheless, I’ll think about your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) a lot, having used it a couple times in production systems.

Something quirky about it is that in version 2 it supported generating C++ code but not C, whereas in version 3 it supports generating C code but not C++.  I like C++ and so still use ANTLR v2, but you will probably enjoy v3.  So much the better for you.

Many distros have ANTLR v2 packages, and some have v3 as well.  It's fairly well documented (note that I use v2; I hope v3 is not worse in this regard).

ANTLR does not generate super awesome parsing error messages "out of the box."  This seems to be something common to most general parser systems, and is fundamentally not an easy problem to solve.  With some work, however, I've seen some decent diagnostic output coming from an ANTLR-based system (the application had some logic to help figure out what to say to the user--ANTLR doesn't have much magic here).

Comment: I am a bit sceptical on the java dependency that this will add to my project at compile-time -- did I get this right?

Comment: It is true that you will need Java available to run the code generator.  But Java is available more or less everywhere, and if there's a place it isn't available, there's no reason you couldn't just generate the code on another platform and compile it on the weird one.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative to Lex & Yacc is the [Lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) parser.  It has quite a lot going for it, but I have not used it in earnest, so I'm not completely sure how well it really works.  It is used by SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/).  I recently started using it and have found it a pleasure to work with once you get up to speed.  In your example, you might do something like (note: not tested!):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

%%{
    machine my_cmd_lang;

    action pk { printf("Killing %.*s\n", fpc-mark, mark); }
    action mk { mark = fpc; }

    k = 'kill'; # creates a machine that doesn't do anything
    x = 'exit' @{ printf("Exiting\n"); };
    arg = alpha+ >mk; # arg to kill is built in machine 'alpha' 1 or more times
    cmd = ((k space arg) @pk space* ';'?) | x;
    main := cmd* ;
}%%

%% write data;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int cs;
    char* p = "kill client";
    char* pe = p + strlen(p);
    char* mark;

    %% write init;
    %% write exec;

    return 0;
}
```

Run it through Ragel with `ragel <filename.rl>` and it will spit out `<filename.c>`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a lexerless parser (e.g., an implementation of [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)). As you're using C and already familiar with yacc, something like [this](http://piumarta.com/software/peg/) might be worth trying.

And if your grammar is simple enough, you can implement an ad hoc recursive descent parser instead.

Comment: I actually stumbled upon peg/leg before asking this question, but the following points have made me lose interest: There seems to be relatively sparse documentation (only the manpage?). It is not packaged for Debian and does not seem to be in active development either.

Comment: @Michael, can't help then - I ended up writing my own implementation of Packrat. Probably you're bound to do the same, it is not that complicated after all.